# read indefinite amount of integers and print on file

Tags: c, file, realloc

*this program read integers until one is negative then prints on a file a characteristic of each of them: how many integers it can be divided by. the problem is that it keeps asking for integers even when i inseert negative ones. please let me know if you can a way to fix this without changing too much of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int checkdiv(int *n);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int *p;
    int i, j;
    FILE *fp;
    int amount;
    i=0;
    p=NULL;

    if(fp = fopen("ris.txt", "w")){
        do{i++;
        p=realloc(p,sizeof(int)*i);
        scanf("%d", (p+i-1));
        amount=checkdiv(p+i-1);
        if(amount!= -1);
        fprintf(fp,"%d  %d\n", *(p+i-1),amount);
        }while(p+i-1>0);

    }else{
        printf("errore");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
int checkdiv(int *n){
int i;
int amount=0;
for(i = 2;i < *n; i++){
    if(*n % i == 0){
        amount++;
    }
}
if(*n <= 0){
    amount= -1;
}
return amount;
}
```

Comment: You don't want the semicolon in `if(amount!= -1);`

Comment: "the problem probably resides in the do while cycle." -- Which problem? What's your input? What's the output you expect and what is the output you actually get?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. `p+i-1` is a pinter to the `i - 1`th element. In the `while` condition, you want to check whether what it points at is positive, not the pointer itself. (By the way, if you just wat to print the information for each read integer, you don't need to allocate memory. Just handle the integers as tey are read in.)

Comment: Note that if you compiled with `-Wall` [on `clang`] or `-Wall` and `-Wempty-statement` [on `gcc`], then `if(amount!= -1);` would be _flagged_ with a warning

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in:

```
}while(p+i-1>0);
```

must be;

```
}while(*(p+i-1)>0);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should remove semi colon in line

```
if(amount!=-1);
```

so that the statement below it can be included in if block.